# Automatically sort a DataGridView when done editing a cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple, unbound DataGridView. I want a particular column to autosort after any cell is edited.  I tried to call `dataGridView1.Sort` when a `CellEndEdit` event is fired, but I get a **InvalidOperationException** with the message *Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.*

Any idea how I can make the column auto-sort?

Comment: Send the event handler code

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to call the `dataGridView1.Sort()` in `CellEndEdit` event handler, the column will be sorted automatically for you after editing cell. You just need to specify which column to sort and the order (ascending or descending) to sort **once** for example in your form constructor:

```
//This will sort ascendingly the first column
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Then, every time user finishes editing a cell in the first column, that column will be sorted automatically.

### UPDATE

If the `DataGridView` is not data-bound, I tried placing the code line above in a `CellEndEdit` event handler and it worked OK. I'm not sure why it didn't work for you?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Just care the first column
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I added that code to the constructor, but nothing happens. It may only apply to DataGridViews with bound data source?

Comment: @TimHopper please see my update, are you sure that's what you did?

Answer (score 1):

On Load Event put:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

For UPDATE you need to use the follows two event:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{    
      dataGridView1.EndEdit();

}


private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Just care the first column
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution on sorting a grid after cell end edit, and avoiding the "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function" exception.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Just care the first column
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(DoSortGrid));
}

private void DoSortGrid(){        
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;//Keep the current row in view for large list
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tell your binding source to sort and specify the column you wish to sort by. Example:

```
this.table1BindingSource.Sort = "person";
```

Comment: This is an unbound DataGridView.